# AngularJS not interpreting the condition expression correctly

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angularjs the ng-style to format the text with a color if the condition is met, but for some reason, the Lexer gives an error:

> Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns
> 23-24 ['] in expression [asignadap.tipoFlag === '].

This is my code:

```
ng-style="object.type == 'type 2' && {'color':'#e30754'}"
```

If i substitute with a number it works.

I don't quite understand why with text the condition doesn't work, i have tried these variations of the condition:

```
ng-style="object.type == '"type 2"' && {'color':'#e30754'}"
ng-style="object.type == \\"type 2\\" && {'color':'#e30754'}"
```

How i compare the variable with text correctly?

From the console, the error on how it's interpreting the expression:

```
ng-style="object.type === '" type="" 2"'="" &&="" {'color':'#e30754'}"=""
```

Answer (score 1):

Imho code like `a && b` is not always good when a and b can be of different types. Plain JS allows too much, angularjs parser allows much less. In your case just use ternary operator:

```
object.type == 'type 2' ? {color:'#e30754'} : {}
```